# Как работает система сборки?

Tags: java, maven

Мне необходимо передать другому человеку мавеновский проект написанный в IDEA и возникает вопрос - что именно передавать? 
Насколько я понял систему, передаются папки .idea , src и файл POM. Дальше с помощью команды

> mvn install

собирается проект в локальном репозитории. Я правильно понял?

Когда я выполняю эту команду выдается BUILD SUCCESSFUL

```
C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ParagonCase 1.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocate
d to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ParagonCas
e ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ParagonCase ---

[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Pa
ragonCase ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Paragon
Case ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ ParagonCase ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\target\
surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running MainTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.118 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ ParagonCase ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ParagonCase ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\target\ParagonCase-1.2.
jar to C:\Users\Kru\.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\ParagonCase-1.2.j
ar
[WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Users\Kru\.m2
\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\_remote.repositories
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\pom.xml to C:\Users\Kru
\.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\ParagonCase-1.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Users\Kru\.m2
\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\_remote.repositories
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.874 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-31T20:25:37+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Однако по завершению в локальном репозитории ничего не появляется.

Comment: а что вы проверяете? у вас явно в логе указано Installing ... to C:\Users\Kru\.m2\repository\ru\nick\kru\ParagonCase\1.2\ParagonCase-1.2.j
ar

Comment: Именно эту папку я и смотрю

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Структура каталогов Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Если вы хотите передать **исходный код**, то необходимо передать:

- каталог `src`;
- `pom.xml`;
- конфигурационные файлы и ресурсы, используемые в вашем проекте, если они не находятся внутри каталога `src`.

Расшарить проект удобно через систему контроля версий, например, Git. Для этого потребуется хостинг, который позволяет хранить git репозитории, которые могут быть публичными или приватными. Бесплатные сервисы: [Github](https://github.com/), [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

---

Если выхотите передать **собранный дистрибутив**, т.е. JAR файл в вашем случае, то он формируется в директории `target/`:

`C:\Users\Kru\IdeaProjects\PopularWords\target\ParagonCase-1.2.jar`

Это каталог, в который, по умолчанию, собирается сам проект, а также сохраняется временные файлы, используемые Maven и его плагинами в процессе сборки.

В локальный репозиторий Maven артифакт устанавливается для того, чтобы ваши другие проекты могли использовать его как зависимость. Чтобы не устанавливать собранный проект в локальный репозиторий, используйте для сборки команду [`mvn package`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics).

`.idea/`, `.iml`, `.project`, `.settings/`, `.classpath` и прочие файлы и каталоги, начинающиеся в точки, это обычно конфигурационные файлы и ресурсы вашей IDE, OS и других приложений. Некоторые из этих файлов нужно передавать, например, `.gitignore`, `findbugs-exclude.xml`, но в таких случаях вы обычно знаете что это за файлы и зачем они нужны.